# Phasor with source

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, phasor

[image]

220 muF stands for \$220\cdot10^{-6} F\$. Sorry for putting it that way.

The question is to find the equivalent impedance Z with a frequency = 50 Hz. I know how to find all the Z of the capacitor and inductor, but I am confused what to do afterwards. Should I try current division or something?

Comment: nice schematic by the way. Also: if you want to have it easier next time: this site comes with a built-in schematics editor, which does your job perfectly well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 3 times the current that flows into the capacitor is conducted by the current source, then that is no different than three additional capacitors in parallel with your original one!

So, replace the dependent current source with three more 220 uF caps in parallel, making a total of four. Then, finish your calculations :)

Comment: Could you possibly draw a schematic for me? I think I understand but I'm not completely sure haha xD

Comment: It would be more correct to say "replace the dependent current source with three *more* 220 uF caps in parallel, making a total of four."

Comment: @DaveTweed yeah. will use that wording.

Comment: @T.Bui is it clearer now, with Dave's wording? Not so sure what you could be uncertain about...

Comment: @MarcusMüller Just tried it using your way and I got the correct answer! Thank you very much for all your help!